# Quickbooks : Fetching all transactions from Quickbooks table?

Tags: php, quickbooks

I'm using PHP Quickbooks Devkit 2.0 for developing an application. I have downloaded it from consolibyte.
My question is how to request for fetching all transactions from the quickbooks db?
Now my request xml is like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
    <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <TransactionQueryRq>
     <FromModifiedDate>1990-01-01T00:00:00</FromModifiedDate>
                    </TransactionQueryRq>   
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>
```

Please anyone suggest is their any problem with this xml??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes at last I found it. problem is that when we request for transaction from quickbooks we have to send response xml with qbxml version greater than or same as 4. so I modified code like this :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="4.0"?>
    <QBXML>
      <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <TransactionQueryRq>
      <FromModifiedDate>1990-01-01T00:00:00</FromModifiedDate>
                </TransactionQueryRq>   
       </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>
```

It works!!!